# Mean of (more than) two rank-1 positive semi-definite matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, interpolation, average, positive-semidefinite

I've already spent some time researching literature, but wasn't able to find any answer to my question.

Maybe you can help?

Let's assume a set of $i \geq 2 \in \mathbb{N}$ rank-1 positive semi definite matrices $\boldsymbol{A}_i$ with corresponding normalized weights $w_i$. $\boldsymbol{A}_i$ has only one non-zero eigenvalue, which is assumed to be 1 for each matrix in our set.
We can then express $\boldsymbol{A}_i$ by means of dyadics $\boldsymbol{A}_i = \boldsymbol{n}_i \otimes \boldsymbol{n}_i$, wherein the vectors $\boldsymbol{n}_i$   are unit-vectors $\boldsymbol{n}_i \cdot  \boldsymbol{n}_i = 1$.

Now, I've two questions:

1. Is there an formula/algorithm to determine a weighted mean of two dyadic tensors $\boldsymbol{A}_1 = \boldsymbol{n}_1 \otimes \boldsymbol{n}_1 $ and $\boldsymbol{A}_2 = \boldsymbol{n}_2 \otimes \boldsymbol{n}_2$, such that the averaged value $\boldsymbol{\bar{A}} $ preserves the characteristics of its arguments and can also be expressed as dyadic tensor $\boldsymbol{\bar{A}} = \boldsymbol{\bar{n}} \otimes \boldsymbol{\bar{n}}$?
2. If yes, is there an generalization of this approach for an arbritary set of dyadics tensors?

Help would be really appreciated.

What I've figured out so far:

- It's obvious an Euclidean approach $\boldsymbol{\bar{A}}_\text{EU} = \sum_i w_i \boldsymbol{A}_i$ doesn't work in the general case, since it would alter the rank of the averaged matrix.
- There exists an affine approach for positive definite matrices [1](https://ronnybergmann.net/mvirt/manifolds/SymPosDef.html). However, the formulas used involve matrix logarithms and exponentials that are only well defined for this specific group of matrices.
- I've tried to visualize it for a 2D-case. Assume the matrix $\boldsymbol{A} = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \beta & \gamma  \end{pmatrix}$. From the positive semi-definite condition, we know that $\alpha \geq 0$, $\gamma \geq 0$, $\alpha \gamma - \beta^2 = 0$. This implicit equation is illustrated by the cone in the figure. For our set of matrices we knew that $\alpha + \gamma = 1$. So all matrices in our set are on the red line. I wish to interpolate between two points on the line in such a way, that the interpolated values is also on this line. [Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdaXW.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "preserves the characteristic s of its arguments"?

Comment: Also, what is the [1] doing there? Did you mean to add a link?

Comment: What requirements is this average supposed to satisfy? Specifically, how the weights $w_i$ are supposed to factor into it? As is, you can just take the weighted average of $n_i$ and make a dyadic out of it.

Comment: Thanks for your remarks. Link is now working.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom e.g. in the field of unit quaternions we can use [SLERP ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) for two values or use the Frechet-Mean on $SO(3)$ for an arbritary number of values. That would guarantee the averaged value to have the same characteristics as the values we used as input. In this case it is also an unit quaternion

Comment: @Conifold tried to add an illustration in the post above. Hope it helps.

Comment: [Riemannian Metric and Geometric Mean for Positive Semidefinite Matrices of Fixed Rank by Bonnabel and  Sepulchre](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/080731347) introduces a mean defined on semi-definite matrices that preserves rank. Perhaps it will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those, who are interested:
Took me some time to understand and implement the method proposed by [Bonnabel](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/080731347). Thanks for the hint, @Conifold.

The method does exactly what I want it to do:
interpolate between two rank-1 matrices , preserving the relevant characteristics:

- rank of the $\boldsymbol{A}_1, \boldsymbol{A}_2$
- trace of $\boldsymbol{A}_1, \boldsymbol{A}_2$

For the 2d case i have illustrated the interpolation results in component space:

[image]

One remark, since @Conifold proposed to average directly on the vectors.
$\boldsymbol{A}_i = \boldsymbol{n}_i \otimes \boldsymbol{n}_i = -\boldsymbol{n}_i \otimes -\boldsymbol{n}_i $. Due to this sign ambiguity, it is not possible to determine an averaged vector in an unique way and then, construct a dyadic matrix from it.

Some further remarks:

I want to do a mesh-to-mesh mapping that involves tensor fields. Euclidean approaches (a.k.a. component averaging) yield non-sense results, since they induce artifical minima and maxima in tensor invariants, that are non-physical. My discrete set of tensors usually contains negative-definite and semi-definite entries, so I cannot use the Riemannian approach ("geometric mean"). Therefore, I try to use a decomposition-reassembling approach on tensor shape and tensor orientation. There are a lot of methods described in literature, usually operating on spectral/eigen decomposition $\boldsymbol{A} = \boldsymbol{Q} \boldsymbol{\Sigma} \boldsymbol{Q}^\top$ with $\boldsymbol{Q} \in SO(3)$. Problem is that $\boldsymbol{Q}$ is not unique and chosing an "reference rotation" violates the isotropy-condition, meaning results will depend on the specific coordinate system. Therefore I try to use an approach, that operates on the projector decomposition $\boldsymbol{A} = \sum_i \lambda_i \boldsymbol{P}_i$ with $\gamma_i$ being the Eigenvalues. Now, I'm looking for a method to average/interpolate on those projectors $\boldsymbol{P}_i$. One option is to use Euclidean method, again, minimize the Frobenius distance to find the closest rank-1 projector, but this yields weighted averages, that are very close to the support points (cf. figure below: red spheres). So, the method from Bonnabel is very promising for me.

[image: figure2]
Sorry for the missing decorations, done this on the fly.

Comment: I am curious if you wish the mean to have rank exactly $1$, or just $\leq 1$. The space of rank $p$ SPSD matrices is not contractible, and Bonnabel-Sepulchre mean is not uniquely defined for "antipodal" matrices. On the other hand, the space of rank $\leq p$ SPSD matrices is contractible, and the affine mean mentioned in the OP extends to it by continuity, see [Geometric means by Ando et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379503008693). It is always iniquely defined and works for more than two matrices, but can drop rank. In particular, for $p=1$ the mean can be $0$.

Comment: Yes, I want the mean to be a rank-1 projector, i.e. $\boldsymbol{\bar{A}} \boldsymbol{\bar{A}} = \boldsymbol{\bar{A}}$ and $\mathrm{trace}\left( \boldsymbol{\bar{A}} \right) = 1$.
As I understand "antipodal" means $\boldsymbol{A}_1 \boldsymbol{A}_2^\top = \boldsymbol{I}$. I think that's not possible for two rank-1 projectors.

Comment: That's odd, $\boldsymbol{A}_1 \boldsymbol{A}_2^\top = \boldsymbol{I}$ wouldn't be possible for any rank deficient matrices. But the matrices on the "opposite" sides of the ellipse in your picture should not have a unique mean.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But that is more than unlikely, since I use to deal with experimental data. I've found, that [Bonnabel](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379512008646) extended their approach to capture more than two matrices. This appears to be rather complex for my standards. unfortunately, this is just a side project and am I'm cleary no mathematician, so I try to find some time for understandig

Comment: I didn't know about the second paper, thanks. Makes sense, there is a general construction of means for any number when there is a metric, but it is nice that it is computationally tractable in this case. You have better intuition than me, why is it important that the rank of the mean matrix (and that it is a projector) be preserved? Naively, it seems that for antipodes the mean should be $0$ (or lower rank and not necessarily a projector, generally).

Comment: I've added some background information to the anwser.

Comment: I wish I could upvote it again :) Btw, you can accept your own answer.